# NodeJs express app is not publishing on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cloud, azureservicebus

I am new to azure cloud service. I want to publish nodejs (express) api on as azure nodejs cloud service. I follow below link to create express app in nodejs.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-express-app/

Above tutorial is very good. I am able to create express app and i run successfully on azure emulator.

Problem :- But when i publish on cloud it also published successfully (hope so) but when i am trying to open web-service URL , it gives me 500 Internal Server error.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Maybe you can remote login to the instance of your cloud service, manually run your application through command line. Normally your application will be deployed at E:/approot/ folder (or maybe some place else I'm not pretty sure). Then you can `node server.js`. If it doesn't work then it might because some files (maybe under node_modules) is missing. If it works then I guess some configuration was wrong inside the cspkg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was create problem because of long path issue in windows system. My code is in E/TestCode/Azure/Sample so npm azure module installed inside sample folder so it creates long hierarchy path. So some module did not upload to Azure.

Solution :- I moved code to E drive and publish it and it works perfectly fine.