# Deploying express node.js project to azure 500 server error

Tags: node.js, azure, express

Seem to have tried every available solution even though some claim that Azure have fixed this issue internally, but I cannot get it to work, production deployment gives me a 500 error every time. Deploying locally works. Here's my app.js which is basically "out of the box" with express 4.12.2

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
           console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
           });
```

Comment: seeing your code doesn't help diagnose your deployment problem... post your deployment steps and errors

Comment: I'm just pushing a local git repo to azure as demo'd in Azure's docs here... http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/

Comment: With the only difference being that I'm using express

Comment: and your file is named `server.js` in the git repo root, as described in these docs?

Comment: can you post your Azure deployment URL

Comment: you have committed your node_modules folder, as described in [these docs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/)?

Comment: Are the packages you're using on the package.json file? We will try and restore them for you. Also, to see the real error message, enable logging at Settings -> Diagnostics & logs and then use the "Streaming log" option so you can get real time view of what is happening and what causes the 500.

Comment: @PanagiotisKefalidis I can't see where to enable that? I have a skeleton project created in terminal with `express ./folder` and then added the port and server code as above in my app.js file.

Comment: @plato yes, I have tried the file named as either app.js or server.js, according to the docs that shouldn't matter but tried both, installed dependencies also yes.

Comment: so, doesn't that mean your server is in ./folder/server.js instead of ./server.js ?

Comment: well it's only in that folder locally, which is the root locally if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @plato though you may well be right according to this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044124/nodejs-express-app-is-not-publishing-on-azure so now my question is how I do it on a mac

Comment: @OliverJ90 can you post the repo url, it would help for us to see it

Comment: @plato https://github.com/OJcode14/nodejs

Comment: Alright well i'm out of ideas. It looks good to me and runs on my local machine. Hopefully @PanagiotisKefalidis 's logging suggestion is helpful

Comment: It works locally on my end too. Its just the azure deployment that doesn't work.

Comment: Any luck guys? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be getting this error in the logs.

`Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\views\layouts\main.handlebars'
    at Error (native)`

[Enable the error logs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-streaming-logs-and-console/)

Note the path to the views folder.

You could try remove the www file. Check the last couple of paragraphs in the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html) on how.

Also I found that adding `app.use(express.static('public'));` is needed if you have resources like images and fonts – it would fail silently otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your entry point is in the root folder.

In my case, my entry point was './bin/www', I had to manually move this file to root and update the  and  sections in the Web.config to get it working.

Deploy again after making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

there were a couple solutions provided in the following question

[Azure NodeJS Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\views\'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417210/azure-nodejs-error-enoent-open-d-home-site-wwwroot-bin-views)

for now I simply used the following near the top of app.js
process.chdir(__dirname);

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very tricky to handle such scenarios.

1. Try to understand/google what versions of nodejs azure portal supports. It supports only specific versions. Note those versions and try to use any version you need or try using latest version only from that list.
2. In azure portal -> go to your app service -> you should see console in appservice details -> Type node -v.
3. This should give you node version may be like 0.10.4 or so. This may be the main main and main culprit.
4. Go to your app settings under configuration for your app service. Add node version there like WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION as your node version ex: 8.9.4
5. Go to your package.json and add node version same as you used in azure portal  appsettings. ex:  "engines": {
   "node": "8.9.4"
   }
6. Restart app service -> check console -> node -v.
   if this shows same version then deploy application and it should work with out any issues.

---

How to check real errors instead of 500

1. In azure portal for your app service enable diagnostic logs
2. Select log stream
3. Refresh your site. Now you should see real error message in log stream.

Good luck.