# Express Applications throwing 500 on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

The following code runs perfectly locally...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World");
});

var port = 8080;

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started and is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

But when i deploy it to azure I get a 500 error. Here is my findings...

1. I have taken this [advice](http://willi.am/blog/2014/05/07/running-express-4-sites-on-azure/)
2. Have tried all possible combinations of server.js, app.js, directory structure etc.

The code is being deployed from a local git repo.

Comment: Are you using Azure web apps or VM's?

Comment: Azure web apps for sure..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610430/deploying-express-node-js-project-to-azure-500-server-error/55989030#55989030

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure Web Apps (web sites) listen on ports 80 and 443 only. You can not listen on port 8080.

You'll need to listen on port `process.env.PORT`. And you can easily run both locally and in Azure by tweaking your port code to something like:

`var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;`