# listen to UDP server from azure web apps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am building a web app using node.js and the azure web app service.  My node.js server is supposed to accept UDP data from client devices, but I am having difficult time setting this up.

Does any form of azure web app service accept data from ports other than TCP 80 and 443?  Can an azure web app linux docker container be setup to accept data from a specific UDP port?

Comment: Yes that should be supported. Have you set up your network security groups properly, so that they forward UDP?

Comment: @sebastian87 I believe that the questions is specific to WebApps, as oppose to a VM, so intheRed would not have any NSGs to configure.

Comment: Yes I'm using a WebApp.  From this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic, it seems that I may be able to set it up if I add a VNET to the webapp service.  That requires Standard Plan which is ~$70/mo.. :-(

Comment: @sebastian87 thanks for the hint, I think this route may work but could be expensive, I'll circle back.

Comment: I've given up on this... it seems to be impossible to setup in Azure. I will just resort to reprogramming the remote devices POST via HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure App Service is restricted to TCP 80/443. See [Express Applications throwing 500 on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117795/express-applications-throwing-500-on-azure/36118614#36118614).

If you need to listen on a port different from 80/443, you'd need to deploy to a Virtual Machine which supports any TCP/UDP ports.